# File sorting problem

Tags: .net, sorting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)
>   [How would I sort a list of files by name to match how Windows Explorer displays them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012985/how-would-i-sort-a-list-of-files-by-name-to-match-how-windows-explorer-displays-t)

Greetings everyone!!!

I am facing a problem when getting files with the method Directory.GetFiles. I have files in the following sequence in my directory.

Slide1.png, Slide2.png,Slide3.png,Slide4.png and so on.

When i get the files it returns in the format Slide1.png, Slide10.png, Slide11.png,Slide12.png, Slide2.png,Slide21.png and so on...

It is sorting with the file name and combining the same values. i am trying Array.sort() but its not sorting as i want. i want the following sequence.

Slide1.png, Slide2.png,Slide3.png,Slide4.png and so on.

I am using VB.NET Framework version 4.0.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of the .Net Framework are you using?  Please tag your question to indicate that you are using .Net Framework + the language you're using.

Comment: What is the sort order it is using, and can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pad the numbers with zeroes, like so:

```
Slide01.png
Slide02.png
...
Slide10.png
...
```

I've had many problems with this myself, so if you have many of them to do (I had 600 images), try a batch renamer, like [Metamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: there are ways and means of doing this without resorting to touching the file names.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the `.NET` reference. I thought this was a generic OS question. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for us that in terms of strings, 1,10,2 is the correct order. While in numbers obviously its not.

Heres an article I found a bit back, which covers this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx