# Sorting Files By Name same as windows in C#

Tags: c#, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

i have been looking around for some code to sort my files by name the same as windows,

My dir contains files `"SD-Patch-1.sql", "SD-Patch-2.sql" ..., "SD-Patch-10.sql"` this is how windows formats them but in my application when sorting by name it sorts them

```
SD-Patch-1.sql
SD-Patch-10.sql
... to 19
SD-Patch-2.sql
```

how do I get the same sort as windows to get the above im using

```
FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
Array.Sort(files, (f1, f2) => f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name));
```

Comment: Who else read this question and thought 'Easy bit of linq should do the job' then got here to find it was more complex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012985/how-would-i-sort-a-list-of-files-by-name-to-match-how-windows-explorer-displays

Comment: personally i rename my files to have the leading zeros in them, but surely a nifty comparer could do the trick.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C

Comment: is there no way though Linq do i have to all the Windows API to sort them i thought there would be a way though Linq that i jsut could not think off?

Comment: A very simple (but brittle) approach is to do: `var files = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Replace("SD-Patch-", ""))).ToList();`

Answer (score -1):

You should use custom comparer in the sort parameter

```
list.Sort(new customComparer());
```

the Comparer should look something like this:

```
class customComparer: IComparer<Object>
{
  public int Compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
  {
    //implament your own code for sorting any way you want
  }
}
```

One example of code for your case could be as fallow.

Create dictionary mapping each later to a corresponding number, something like this:

```
//Mapping between file name characters and their corresponding number of choice
Dictionary<char, int> alphaNumDict = new Dictionary<char, int>()
                                                  {
                                                      {'a',1},
                                                      {'b',2},
                                                      {'c',3},
                                                      {'d',4},
                                                      {'e',5}
                                                      ...
                                                  };
```

Then you can use a simple method to change string to a number and compare the strings' values:

```
//iterate over the string and convert it to a corresponding number
double sum =0;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
    sum += alphaDict[myString[i]] * Math.Pow(10, i);
}
```

Now all you need to do is compare the number you get and return which is bigger

Comment: That's obvious thing. He has to create his custom comparer. What matters is what should be written here (`//implement your own code for sorting any way you want`) and what you write.

Comment: You are right, i added code suggestion.