# How to get all files from a folder in sorted order in C#.Net?

Tags: c#

I would like to get all file inside the windows 7 folder(directory) in the same order as it is shown in the windows 7 viewing pane .

The issue i am getting is that, the function Directory.GetFiles() is returing the name of all the files but in a different sort order, which i do not want. I want the sort order as can be seen from windows viewing pane. Plz guide

PS: I have read other similar question on this site, but i was not able to completely understand the solution. Looking for easier and easy to understand solution

Comment: ... Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11788981/622391) - the accepted answer links to some python sample code which does what you want. It's pretty complex though...