# Get the sorting of the explorer window in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I sort a list of files by name to match how Windows Explorer displays them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012985/how-would-i-sort-a-list-of-files-by-name-to-match-how-windows-explorer-displays)

The C# program I am making is a picture manager. Of course, if I double click on an image in the windows explorer, it opens the image with my program. The program also gets all the images in the same folder, to allow switching from one to another.

I would like to know, if this is possible, how to get the sorting of the explorer window (if it was sorted by Name, by Type, by Modification Date...), to have the same sorting in my program, so that the user can navigate between images in my program exactly in the same order that he sees when opening an image.

Thanks

Comment: So what happens when the user opens your app and then changes the sort order?  Or launches your app from the commandline/powershell?

Comment: @Dan-o : If application is launched from a command line, then I use a default sorting. And I dont specialy want to update the sorting if the user changes it after starting the program.

Comment: @JeremyThompson : The title may be understood in the same way, but the question is not the same. He wanted to use the same sorting algorithm than Windows Explorer. I want to use the same sorting parameters as a precise Windows Explorer window.